# NSDictionary vs NSArray - Books, Chapters And Verses Of The Bible

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

Is this the most efficient way to do this?

I would like to store all of the Books of the Bible (66),  the numbers of chapters in each book and the number of verses in each chapter.

Then use those values for selectors

1. User chooses the book. I set the chapter selector to be the proper range (1-xx)
2. User chooses the chapter. I set the verse selector to be the proper range (1-xx)

So I was thinking it would be best to create two NSArrays (Books, Chapters)

And one NSDictionary (Verses)

Use the index from Books to look up the number of Chapters (range 1-xx)
Use both indexes from Books & Chapters to look up the number of verses (range 1-xx)

Is there a better way to store this structure?
I want to make sure it is the fastest

Answer (score 0):

you can you below class,add this code in the top of your **viewController.m** file.

```
interface BOOK : NSObject
@property NSString *bookName;
@property NSInteger numberOfChapters;
@property NSArray *verseArray;
@end

@implementation BOOK

@end
```

All you had to have is just one array.
@property NSMutableArray *books;
books =[NSmutableArray array];
For example to create a book.

```
BOOK *b =[[BOOK alloc] init];
b.bookName =@"some name";
b.numberOfChapters =3;
b.verseArray =@[@10,@11,@14];
[books addObject:b]; // this way use for loop, and objects to your array.
```

So, in your picker when someone selects a row, use its index to get book

```
Book *selectedBook =books[index];
```

Comment: So, for my use I just really need to create one BOOK object. That makes sense.  

But I still need to store all of the possible values in my code somewhere. What is the best way to store these so I can retrieve one as needed?  

66 of these

bookName =@"some name";
numberOfChapters =3;
verseArray =@[@10,@11,@14];

Comment: updated the answer.if you still have any doubts, feel free to post here.

Answer (score 0):

It's all going to depend on how you plan to use the data within your code. For example, if you're going to present a table of contents and the user will simply click on the name of a book, then you can use an array because you know the order they are in. If instead the user will type the name of a chapter they want, then dictionary would be more appropriate because you'd look up the chapter by name.

As far as efficiency goes, speed of access will be negligible because you have so few items in each array or dictionary. There are fewer than 1,000 books in the bible, fewer than 1,000 chapters in each book and fewer than 1,000 verses in each chapter. Your code won't be in a tight loop accessing thousands of items, so speed-wise, it won't make any difference for this use.